# How to Remove an dropdown Item by finding Text

Tags: c#, dropdownbox

I am databinding my dropdown in the code behind as such

```
AttributeStatusDdl.Items.Clear();
        AttributeStatusDdl.DataSource = StatusDs;
        AttributeStatusDdl.DataTextField = "AttributeStatus";
        AttributeStatusDdl.DataValueField = "AttributeStatus";
        AttributeStatusDdl.DataBind();
```

Now I would like find any items which is a string 'Test' to be removed... How can i achieve this task..
I have tried using findByText but  somehow not able to remove the items with text Test...  Thank you in advance

```
myDropDown.Items.Remove(myDropDown.Items.FindByValue("Test"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, try this one

```
for(int i= AttributeStatusDdl.Items.Count -1; i>= 0; i--)
{
    if (AttributeStatusDdl.Items[i].Text == "a")
        AttributeStatusDdl.Items.RemoveAt(i);
}
```